# Are there any differences in execution when running a single or all test in a test class

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mstest

Does anyone know if there is a difference in the execution process (eg. "vstest.executionengine.exe") when you run a single or when you run all tests in a test class from within Visual Studio Update 3, (compiled to x64 and.Net 4.5.2)?

Running "all tests.." makes a specific test fail. 
But running single test (same specific test) succeeds

The specific test uses a dbContext (Entity Framework 6.x) within a using clause and it seems that the dbContext somehow gets cached when running all tests, thereby making the specific test fail so to speak...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. IMHO, UnitTests should not hit a database.
2. To your question, when you run single vs all, the "all" is when it creates those folders like

> \TestResults\MyUserName_MyMachineName 2016-12-31 14_45_48\In
>   \TestResults\MyUserName_MyMachineName 2016-12-31 14_45_48\Out

Whenever I've had an issue with this, it has been that I didn't have a [DeploymentItem] attribute on some file that was needed for the UnitTest.

(When the UnitTest run as a single, the file would be in the \bin\Debug\ folder, but when it ran as "run all", it would not be in the "\TestResults\MyUserName_MyMachineName 2016-12-31 14_45_48\  " (in some subfolder here) folder, thus the UnitTest would fail.

That is why DeploymentItem exists, to force copy the file into the "run all" area.

Comment: Hi grandaCoder, thanks for quick reply, however 1) the tests I describe are integration tests, 2) When I run the same, eg. run all and the run once using ReSharpers Unit test runner it works without any errors..